# webview get data from input form

Tags: android

How to get value from html from webview using getelementbyid.
I tried several different solutions. I tried with jsoup but i cant reach targeted page becouse user need to be signed in to get to page.

This is input form, i need value data from form

```
  <input class="form-control" id="coupon_code" name="" size="50" type="text" value="https://app.webexample.com/invite?coupon_code=6f7c0f">
```

also i tried to implement `@JavascriptInterface` but it does not work

Comment: You need to add some java script code to get the values. Like a java script that does input validating.

Comment: Why would you want to reach the targetted page? I see no reason.